como connecto mi desarrollo en flutter a una Base de Datos Oracle
Quiero desarrollar (bueno ya realmente iniciamos el desarrollo) de una app , usando flutter (para garantizar un solo ambien te de desarrollo que me genere la aplicacion para ios, android y web), pero deseo que la BD este en Oracle que es nuestro motro de BD usado dentro de la compañia.  pero no encuentro ningun manual , folleto, documento, pagina, que me apoye o ayude a encontrar como podria hacer esa conexion a esa BD ORACLE.  pueden ayudarme para saber como configuraria mi app para usar la BD ORACLE, o si esto es muy complejo que BD me recomendarian que tuviera en el back

Ocupas un servidor intermedio que sea como puente entre flutter y oracle para realizar la conexión. Si te resulta complicado puedes intentar con las bases de datos SQLite, Moor, Ralm, Firebase, etc. Ya depende de lo que necesites.

No conectes directamente una aplicación móvil a una base de datos relacional. Es un problema por donde lo veas, intermitencia de la conexión, seguridad de la DB (que no debiera estar expuesta directamente al Internet), y muchos más. Lo habitual es desarrollar un API que se ejecute en un servidor en la misma red o hasta en la misma máquina de la DB, y que tus aplicaciones hablen con esa API. El tema es amplio y no da para una respuesta de StackOverflow, pero hay mucha información en la red al respecto.

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

como te comentan ahi arriba lo mejor seria hacer una api, puedes hacer con laravel o adonisjs y conectarlo a tu BDD  y asi poder tener acceso sin exponer la seguridad de la misma
